# Android - where are new classes created?

Tags: gridview, baseadapter

I try to get on top of Android (two tutorials successful), I came across this problem: Step 5 of http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html, says "create a new class..." where to create it?

Eclipse says "in its own file", where should the new file be?

Answer (score 0):

Unless there are packages involved, wherever the other classes are.

Comment: if you mean in MainActivity.java, where 'public class MainActivity extends Activity' is defined, then trying to define 'public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter' in that file fails.

Comment: What? No, I mean the same folder as the other classes. Each class should be in its own file. From the sound of it, you might want to take a tutorial in Java before going into Android.